# No module named 'camelot.ext'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-camelot, excalibur-py

I have been trying to run Excalibur after install't from pip, it's asked me to install camelot, after that this error pop up,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/excalibur/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/excalibur/__main__.py", line 10, in main
    from excalibur.cli import cli
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/excalibur/cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .tasks import split, extract
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/excalibur/tasks.py", line 13, in <module>
    from camelot.ext.ghostscript import Ghostscript
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot.ext'
```

this output show when I try to run this model, initdb or webserver command,
I tried many ways to solve't nothing work with me

Answer (score 16):

https://githubmemory.com/repo/camelot-dev/excalibur/issues/144 This fix worked for me after a whole lot of install commands failed.

The error message I was getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/PERSONAL/TECH/python-scratch/python-virtual-environments/py3.8/bin/excalibur", line 5, in <module>
    from excalibur.cli import cli
  File "/mnt/PERSONAL/TECH/python-scratch/python-virtual-environments/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/excalibur/cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .tasks import split, extract
  File "/mnt/PERSONAL/TECH/python-scratch/python-virtual-environments/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/excalibur/tasks.py", line 13, in <module>
    from camelot.ext.ghostscript import Ghostscript
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot.ext'
```

So I edited the mentioned tasks.py file,

Changed `from camelot.ext.ghostscript import Ghostscript`
to  `from ghostscript import Ghostscript`

And then it worked. Prior to this I had just installed Ghostscript, maybe there's a change in the recent packages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pip install camelot-py
```

Comment: This command is the most I tried

Comment: Are you on conda environment?
If you're on conda environment then use this command in anaconda prompt:
conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py

Comment: No, I do not...

Comment: Why are you using camelot.ext.             It could be helpful https://pythonrepo.com/repo/camelot-dev-camelot-python-pdf-files-processing

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing using conda:
`conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py`

Official installation documentation : https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html#install

Also, you should check if path for python has been set correctly.

Comment: i'm using pip not conda