# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot.ext'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-camelot, excalibur-py

**After running 'excalibur webserver ' on jupyter notebook ..i am getting this error -**

```
Input In [15]
excalibur webserver
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**and after running it on cmd i am getting this error -**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\User64390\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\users\User64390\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\User64390\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\excalibur.exe_main.py", line 4, in
File "c:\users\User64390\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\excalibur\cli.py", line 10, in
from .tasks import split, extract
File "c:\users\User64390\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\excalibur\tasks.py", line 13, in
from camelot.ext.ghostscript import Ghostscript
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot.ext'
```

Comment: You can try the solution given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718471/no-module-named-camelot-ext

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'camelot.ext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718471/no-module-named-camelot-ext)